# How can I change the information in a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame table with python?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

For example, I want to numerical all the information in this table:

```
0   30  "blue-collar"   "married"   "basic.9y"  "no"    "yes"   "no"    "cellular"  "may"   "fri"
```

`Yes` change by `1`, `no` by `0`, `basic.9y` by `9`, etc.

Comment: Your question is unclear can you post raw data, code to create the df, the desired result and your attempts

Answer (score 0):

You could use [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html?highlight=replace#pandas.DataFrame.replace) and [astype](https://www.google.com.vn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQhd_-rP3PAhWGvY8KHbngASEQFggeMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fversion%2F0.19.0%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.astype.html&usg=AFQjCNEsFiD5i42Y-bsEmOOEQEdA08HNSA&sig2=Mu1J_frLKu12djP_w9ltDw) to do it.

```
replace({'Yes':1, 'No':0, 'basic.9y':9}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Then `astype` is not necessary. But I think it is more complicated, becuase you need replaced `cellular`, `fri`...

Comment: Thanks, I just think of `astype` for any data that  doesn't become numerical. About other data is his options...

Comment: Sorry , i'm a beginner of  Stack Overflow. I will add all the conditions in detail.